# ASP.NET MVC custom error page not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to configure ASP.NET MVC custom error pages.

I added an `Error` controller with `Index` and `PageNotFound` actions. I also added the following to the `<system.web>` section of my *web.config* file.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

If I type in a URL such as *http://www.example.com/Home/BadPage*, I do in fact see my error handler.

However, can anyone help me understand the following issues and how to work around them?

1. In the case above, it appears that the result code returned to the browser is 200 and not 404. So crawlers such as Google's would have no indication the URL was not found.
2. In some cases, if my controller action determines the URL is not valid, the action will return `HttpNotFound()` as the result. But when this happens, my custom error handler page is *not* displayed. Instead it shows a generic 404 page that appears to be from IIS.

I'm using the current versions of Visual Studio and MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to setting inside **web.config**, you also want to check whether Exception is **HttpException 404** inside **Application_Error**.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Common/Error" mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Common/PageNotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

### Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    // Process 404 HTTP errors
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;
    if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        IController controller = new CommonController();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Common");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");

        var requestContext = new RequestContext(
             new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        controller.Execute(requestContext);
    }
}
```

### CommonController

You also want to return `Response.StatusCode = 404;` inside **PageNotFound** action method.

```
public class CommonController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 503;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return View();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of getting this to work. Couple of questions: 1) Why not just use `Response.Redirect("/Common/PageNotFound")` in your error handler?, and 2) when your code does `Response.Redirect()`, I don't think that returns the error code (such as 404) to the browser for the original URL.

Comment: 1) Ideally, we want to maintain the original URL  in client browser while displaying 404 message. ***Response.Redrect*** causes the round trip to the server, and doesn't maintain the original URL. 2) You can test it using Fiddler.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are avoiding the redirect. Right you are.